# How to get inserted row ID with WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

There is a [GetLastInsertId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.getlastinsertid%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) method in WebMatrix. However, using Reflector, I can see that it's implemented like this:

```
[return: Dynamic]
public object GetLastInsertId()
{
    return this.QueryValue("SELECT @@Identity", new object[0]);
}
```

Which, as  far as I can see, is a very bad way of doing it, because `@@Identity` returns the last insert considering every table and every session. I need this restricted to the scope and session I'm working with, so I was expecting this to use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, since that also seems to be what is most often used according to my reading.

My questions are:

1. Do the WebMatrix wrappers do something that makes this ok to use in my case?
2. If not, is there a simple way to get the inserted ID of an insert query using WebMatrix classes, or should I fall back on stuff like SqlClient for this?

I am interested in answers for SQL Server (not compact) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [David Fowler](http://twitter.com/davidfowl), one of the devs on the Data APIs in WebMatrix: "[SCOPE_IDENITTY] doesn't work on ce". Since we wanted a data API that would work on both CE and regular SQL Server, we used @@Identity. So if you want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY specifically, you should use db.QueryValue method:

```
var db = Database.Open(...);
db.Insert(...);
var lastInsertId = db.QueryValue("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then. Will `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` work as intended the way you've written it? I'm a bit confused because I saw some developers say it should be used in a stored procedure, although the MSDN page on it doesn't use stored procedures.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, you may need to test. It's possible SCOPE_IDENTITY must be in the same batch as the INSERT, so you may need to write your insert as: db.QueryValue("INSERT ... SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", param1, param2, etc.)

Comment: There's actually an easier way using `db.QuerySingle` and `output`: `var db = Database.Open("Test"); var val = "Test param"; var t = db.QuerySingle("insert into Test(TestName) output inserted.TestID as 'InsertedID' values(@0)", val);`. Then `@t.InsertedID` will give the inserted ID for that insert. Note that `TestID` is the identity column in table `Test`. I don't know if this works in the compact edition, however for compact `@@Identity` seems safe to use in most, if not all, scenarios. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote this. I am using it, exactly as pointed out, in the exact environment this is supposed to work in, and I get no data returned. Sorry.

Comment: @IVlad And your comment is the one that helped. Thanks for posting that! I was able to get it with `db.QueryValue()` but the rest of it was the same. This answer should have written the usable code better. It DOES seem to matter that this statement (the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` part) is included and executed at the same time as the insert statement. I couldn't get it to return anything without it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I read these answers but still couldn't get the code to work correctly. I possibly was misreading the solutions above, but what seemed to work for me was as follows:

```
  var db=Database.Open(...);
  var lastInsertID = db.QueryValue("INSERT name into Names; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
var db.Database.open('..');
var lastId = db.GetLastInsertId();
```