# Is it safe to use GetLastInsertId() across scope in a C#.NET WebPages using WebMatrix Environment?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webmatrix

Firstly, I should just mention that I'm working in a C#.NET WebPages environment using WebMatrix (cshtml files).

I'm also using SQL Server Express 2014, if that matters.

Over the last couple of days, I've explored how to insert a new row into a table (`MasterClientChemicals`) and then get the primary key (type-`bigint`; column name-`ID`) for that inserted row returned.

I've used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `@@SCOPE`, `OUTPUT INSERT.ID` (within the insert query), `INDENT_CURRENT` (I've tried them with `SELECT` and I've tried them with `RETURN` such that it looks much like this:

```
saveQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterClientChemicals ";
saveQuery += "(ClientID, CompanyName, MSDS, [MFR NAME], [PROD NAME], [MAX WT], CONT, AREA, [CAS #], [%], [CHEM NAME], [NFPA/FPRACH/GLOES], [Client MSDS], ";
saveQuery += "[Chem % Min], PS, [Specific Gravity], Density, DOT, UFC, [AIR TITLE I VOC PERCENT], [AIR TITLE I VOC VOL], [AIR TITLE I VOC WEIGHT], [Status Date]) ";
saveQuery += "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

var newID = db.Execute(saveQuery, clientID, companyName, CMPMSDS, CMPMFRNAME, CMPPRODNAME, CMPMAXWT, CMPCONT, CMPAREA, CMPCASNumber, CMPPercent, CMPCHEMNAME, NFPAFPRACHGLOES, CMPClientMSDS, CMPChemMin, CMPPS, CMPSpecificGravity, CMPDensity, CMPDOT, CMPUFC, CMPVOCPercent, CMPVOCVolume, CMPVOCWeight, CMPStatusDate);
```

This will be a little different, depending on if I was attempting to use `OUTPUT` or any of the other above attempts I've mentioned.

The problem is that it only ever returns `1` (I'm assuming, based on the research I've done, that this is the number of rows effected, rather than the ID itself. I found this in reference to using some `.ExecuteScalar` C# method, which doesn't seem to be available to me in my environment. I suppose I could try to build something up in my `.cs` file, but it really isn't where I'd like this code to be located if it can be helped. Also, I've never queried databases using this method before, so there's that.

I want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` since it seems that function cares about scope when the others don't, and I must be certain (since multiple users will be working with this interface at the same time), that I get the correct ID for the row just added by the user.

I've set the `ID` column in the table in question to the primary key (this actually had to be added by myself (AS IDENTITY), since this table didn't originally have so much as a composite primary key (don't know if this would even make any kind of difference, so I thought I'd mention it).

I am aware that in my environment there exists a `GetLastInsertID()` which seems to work (it gives me the correct ID), however, when multiple users start using this interface (and its queries to our database) I need to be sure that they won't be tripping over each other.

Is it safe to use `GetLastInsertID()` in this way, or should I be concerned?

If I should be using something else, what else will work in my environment?

What I'm using now (with `GetLastInsertID()`):

```
saveQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterClientChemicals ";
saveQuery += "(ClientID, CompanyName, MSDS, [MFR NAME], [PROD NAME], [MAX WT], CONT, AREA, [CAS #], [%], [CHEM NAME], [NFPA/FPRACH/GLOES], [Client MSDS], ";
saveQuery += "[Chem % Min], PS, [Specific Gravity], Density, DOT, UFC, [AIR TITLE I VOC PERCENT], [AIR TITLE I VOC VOL], [AIR TITLE I VOC WEIGHT], [Status Date]) ";
saveQuery += "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22)";

db.Execute(saveQuery, clientID, companyName, CMPMSDS, CMPMFRNAME, CMPPRODNAME, CMPMAXWT, CMPCONT, CMPAREA, CMPCASNumber, CMPPercent, CMPCHEMNAME, NFPAFPRACHGLOES, CMPClientMSDS, CMPChemMin, CMPPS, CMPSpecificGravity, CMPDensity, CMPDOT, CMPUFC, CMPVOCPercent, CMPVOCVolume, CMPVOCWeight, CMPStatusDate);

var newID = db.GetLastInsertId();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the classes that WebMatrix uses but this seems to be the equivalent of `ExecuteScalar` (which is what you need): [`Database.QueryValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue(v=vs.111).aspx) - If you use this with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` you wont have to worry about concurrency/scope issues.  Failing that there will be a way to use the SqlClient classes from .Net proper.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the reply. I have, indeed, used `db.QueryValue` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but the value it returns is always `1`, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Tried it with the OUTPUT method?

Comment: @AlexK. Actually, yes. The OUTPUT method was the first thing I tried. That returns `1` also, however, I just tried the following (after the `db.Execute` statement, as I have it, above): `db.QueryValue("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")` but I don't think that I'm doing it right, because I'm getting back `null` instead of `1`. Does `db.QueryValue("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")` look right to you? It does to me.

Comment: Yes, your sure that table has an ident column?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753037/how-to-get-inserted-row-id-with-webmatrix

Comment: @AlexK. Oh, yes, I'm sure it's set as Identity and as Primary Key.

Comment: @AlexK. Also, yeah, I saw that post originally and had to downvote it, because it doesn't solve the problem. Not only is there no such method (`db.Insert`) in this environment, but if I use the last line in his answer after my `db.Execute` method (which inserts a new row), I get no data back in return (just as I didn't a minute ago, when I tried `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. It's actually the same thing I just tried, in fact.

Comment: @AlexK. Okay, it seems I've got it to work. Things to consider would be that you can't use the query from my first example above (using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`) with `db.Execute`. It must be used with `db.QueryValue` or another of the `Query` methods, AND appended to the Insert query itself. I couldn't get it to return data or the correct data in any other attempt. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, using my example above (the first one; the one that uses the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`) method can't be used with db.Execute, and instead must be used with a `.QueryValue()` method (or `QuerySingle()`, etc.).

Also, it seems to matter that it is lumped in with the INSERT query itself, as I could not get it to work any other way.

What ended up working for me (and, thus, allowing me to steer clear of `GetLastInsertId()` which doesn't seem to be scope specific):

```
saveQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterClientChemicals ";
        saveQuery += "(ClientID, CompanyName, MSDS, [MFR NAME], [PROD NAME], [MAX WT], CONT, AREA, [CAS #], [%], [CHEM NAME], [NFPA/FPRACH/GLOES], [Client MSDS], ";
        saveQuery += "[Chem % Min], PS, [Specific Gravity], Density, DOT, UFC, [AIR TITLE I VOC PERCENT], [AIR TITLE I VOC VOL], [AIR TITLE I VOC WEIGHT], [Status Date]) ";
        saveQuery += "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

        var newID = db.QueryValue(saveQuery, clientID, companyName, CMPMSDS, CMPMFRNAME, CMPPRODNAME, CMPMAXWT, CMPCONT, CMPAREA, CMPCASNumber, CMPPercent, CMPCHEMNAME, NFPAFPRACHGLOES, 
                   CMPClientMSDS, CMPChemMin, CMPPS, CMPSpecificGravity, CMPDensity, CMPDOT, CMPUFC, CMPVOCPercent, CMPVOCVolume, CMPVOCWeight, CMPStatusDate);
```

I hope this helps find somebody an answer quicker than I found one!